# How to access a swift file from an objective file, while both of them are in Unit Test?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, unit-testing

This problem may still baffling many people, but there is no answer to this question yet.

I have 2 files, both are in the Unit Test directory.
1. A swift extension to NSError. Lets call it **NSErrorExtension.swift**. This extensions contains some static  methods.
2. an objective C test class, lets call it **UnitTest1.m** .

Now, I want to access the static methods in **NSErrorExtension.swift** from **UnitTest1.m**. How do I do this? It just tells me that "No known class methods for selector...." I tried many solutions, none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

Run into the same issue, seems the `MyAppTests-Swift.h` is not very "importable" :)

I had to resort to some not-so-nice workarounds to make this work. For class instantiation I used `NSClassFromString()` and then cast to a protocol visible on the Objective-C side. For your extension you could do something similar by declaring the methods in a header file, without actually implementing them.

So assuming your `NSErrorExtension.swift` extension looks like this:

```swift
extension NSError {
    @objc func someFunc() -> SomeResult
}
```

, you can create a `NSErrorExtension.h` file (without a corresponding `.m` one):

```c
@interface NSError (UnitTestExtensions)
- (SomeResult *)someFunc;
@end
```

This should make the function available on the Objective-C side. The downside is that you'll need to do this for every function you want to expose from the Swift side of the unit tests.